# Integral, limit, sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration, limits

I'm not sure how to formulate the title, but here is a problem I've come across recently and I'm not sure how to go about solving it.

Let $$P_n(x) = \frac{x^n(bx-a)^n}{n!}, \quad a,b,n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Prove that $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} P_n(x) \sin x d x = 0.$$

Could you help me with that?

Comment: You have an upper limit of $x$ but you are integrating with respect to $x$. I think probably you mean $P_n(t)\sin(t)\,dt$.

Comment: The whole expression's absolute value looks like it can be bounded by $c^n / n!\to 0$

Comment: I'm very sorry. I made a mistake. There should be $\pi$, not $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$|P_n(x)| = \left|\frac{x^n(bx-a)^n}{n!}\right|\leq\frac{\pi^n(b\pi+a)^n}{n!}=\frac{{C}^n}{n!}\to0$$
so
$$ \left|\int_{0}^{\pi} P_n(x) \sin x d x\right|\leq \int_{0}^{\pi}| P_n(x)|dx\leq \pi \frac{{C}^n}{n!}\to 0 .$$

Comment: You're welcome.